# Resize a figure automatically in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to automatically resize a figure to properly fit contained plots in a matplotlib/pylab image?

I'm creating heatmap (sub)plots that differ in aspect ratio according to the data used.

I realise I could calculate the aspect ratio and manually set it, but surely there's an easier way?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use **bbox_inches='tight'**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

X = 10*np.random.rand(5,3)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5),facecolor='w') 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(X, cmap=cm.jet)

plt.savefig("image.png",bbox_inches='tight',dpi=100)
```

...only works when saving images though, not showing them.

Comment: What does that fig.add_subplot(111) indicate? I mean the number within the square brackets ((111))

Comment: My answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10448306/1273751) works for showing and saving

Comment: what does dpi=100 do?

Comment: dpi controls the dots per inch. If you are putting the plot on a powerpoint or something, then you would want to increase the dpi for clarity. Alternatively, you could save it with vector graphics.

Answer (score 21):

Another way of doing this is using the matplotlib tight_layout function

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,(ax) = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4), ncols=1)
data = [0,1,2,3,4]
ax.plot(data)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 18):

just use aspect='auto' when you call imshow

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

X = 10*np.random.rand(5,3)
plt.imshow(X, aspect='auto')
```

it works even if it is just for showing and not saving

Comment: this resizes the images instead of the figure

Answer (score 7):

you can try using axis('scaled')

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

#some dummy images
img1 = numpy.array([[.1,.2],[.3,.4]]) 
img2 = numpy.array([[.1,.2],[.3,.4]])

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(img1,extent=[0,1,0,1])
ax.imshow(img2,extent=[2,3,0,1])
ax.axis('scaled') #this line fits your images to screen 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean changing the size of the image or the area that is visable within a plot?

The size of a figure can be set with [Figure.set_figsize_inches](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html).
Also the [SciPy Cookbook](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/AdjustingImageSize) has an entry on changing image size which contains a section about multiple images per figure.

Also take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib).

Comment: I mean the dimensions of the Figure object. i.e. Crop the figure to fit the contained plot(s). One would probably have to provide either a width or a height first, and have the other calculated.

Comment: I think the correct command is ``.set_size_inches`` without the ``fig``

Answer (score 2):

Also possible to use [ax.autoscale](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.autoscale.html) with ax object

```
ax.autoscale(enable=True)
```

Comment: Hm, `enable=True` is already the default value...