# convert one Matplotlib graph into two when there are two many categorical values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the recurrent issue of having matplotlib bar graphs containing too many categorical values in the X axis. [Resize a figure automatically in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271023/resize-a-figure-automatically-in-matplotlib) and [Python matplotlib multiple bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270391/python-matplotlib-multiple-bars) does not make the trick because my x values are not x. I am having the idea of splitting the graph into two graphs when it get past a certain amount of data point in the graph. I cannot find anything about in the matplotlib document, nor anywhere.

Is there a matplotlib tool to do that? or i would need to write an algorithm that detects the length of the dataset?

Comment: How many are too many categories? What should `matplotlib` be doing for you here? This question will likely get flagged as off topic if you can't express your issue with a minimal example (see some help here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or if it should be a feature request on the project github.

Categorical axes are very common and well supported by `matplotlib`, as i'm sure you already know since you've run into this many times. Why should you not have to determine how many categories are too many, and then split your dataset amongs two or more plots?

Comment: i just asked about whether there is a matplotlib tool that does this automatically or if I have to do that on my own. Regardless I feel like it would be a cool feature if it existed.