# matplotlib, how change plot size without affecting axis label

Tags: matplotlib

I want to make a plot in matplotlib that is wide and short. I can manipulate the size of a plot as answered on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332289/1082727).

However, the x-axis label disappears if the plot is not tall enough. I want to squeeze the plot more while keeping the axis label visible.

Is there a way to manipulate the size of the plot without getting rid of the axis label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you change the plot size, run [`tight_layout()`](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html). Note that this requires matplotlib v1.1 or newer. If you have an older version of matplotlib, you can run `subplot_tool()` or `subplots_adjust` to adjust the plot manually.