# Generating multiple heatmaps with the same gradient

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I'm trying to create multiple heatmaps using `matplotlib` using the same code. Ofcourse the data is different for all these heatmaps. And because of this, the intensity of colors across heatmaps is different. Is there a way I can make sure that the range of intensity remains the same? All my values in the heatmaps lie between 0 and 1. So I want the color of the value `0.2` in `heatmap1` to look exactly the same as the color of the value `0.2` in `heatmap2`, even though both heatmaps could have different ranges.

I apologize for the somewhat confusing language of the question, but I don't know how to explain it better.

Here's the code that I'm using to generate heatmaps:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def show_values(pc, fmt="%.2f", **kw):
    '''
    Heatmap with text in each cell with matplotlib's pyplot
    Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25074150/395857 
    By HYRY
    '''
#     from itertools import izip
    try:
        # Python 2
        from itertools import izip
    except ImportError:
        # Python 3
        izip = zip
    pc.update_scalarmappable()
    ax = pc.get_axes()
    for p, color, value in izip(pc.get_paths(), pc.get_facecolors(), pc.get_array()):
        x, y = p.vertices[:-2, :].mean(0)
        if np.all(color[:3] > 0.5):
            color = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        else:
            color = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        ax.text(x, y, fmt % value, ha="center", va="center", color=color, **kw)


df= pd.read_csv("filepath", header=None)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10)) 
heatmap = plt.pcolor(df,cmap=matplotlib.cm.Blues)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(df.shape[0]) + 0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(df.shape[1]) + 0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels, minor=False, rotation=45)
ax.set_yticklabels(ylabels, minor=False)
plt.ylim( (0, df.shape[0]) )
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.title("plot title")
show_values(heatmap)
plt.show()
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determine your minimum and maximum and specify them in the code

```
plt.pcolor(x, y, z, cmap='RdBu', vmin=z_min, vmax=z_max)
```

I pulled this from [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pcolor_demo.html)