# Getting axes of matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I want to get axes of a `matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection`. If pc is such an object, running the code below:

```
ax = pc.axes.get_xaxis()
```

Though my code has been working before, I was encountering the warning below:

> MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: get_axes has been deprecated in mpl 1.5, please use the axes property. A removal date has not been set.

But now I have encountered this error running the same program:

> 'PolyCollection' object has no attribute 'get_axes'

How can I get the axes after depreciation of the get_axes?

Comment: Can you please precisely state which code you are running and what the complete error traceback is. Also state the version you are using.

Comment: My code is a modified version of this code available on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071968/heatmap-with-text-in-each-cell-with-matplotlibs-pyplot/25074150#25074150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning you mention suggests to use the axes property instead. Having a look at the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection), axes is an existing property while get_axes is not. It should return the Axes instance as intended.