# Naive Bayes and SVM classification - how to plot accuracy on x y axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to generate some line graph with an x and y axis demonstrating accuracy of 2 different algorithms running a classification - Naive Bayes and SVM.

I train/test the data like this:

```
# split the dataset into training and validation datasets
train_x, valid_x, train_y, valid_y = model_selection.train_test_split(result['post'], result['type'], test_size=0.30, random_state=1)

# label encode the target variable
encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
train_y = encoder.fit_transform(train_y)
valid_y = encoder.fit_transform(valid_y)

def tokenizersplit(str):
    return str.split()
tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenizersplit, encoding='utf-8', min_df=2, ngram_range=(1, 2), max_features=25000)

tfidf_vect.fit(result['post'])
tfidf_vect.transform(result['post'])

xtrain_tfidf = tfidf_vect.transform(train_x)
xvalid_tfidf = tfidf_vect.transform(valid_x)

def train_model(classifier, trains, t_labels, valids, v_labels):
    # fit the training dataset on the classifier
    classifier.fit(trains, t_labels)

    # predict the labels on validation dataset
    predictions = classifier.predict(valids)

    return metrics.accuracy_score(predictions, v_labels)

# Naive Bayes
accuracy = train_model(naive_bayes.MultinomialNB(), xtrain_tfidf, train_y, xvalid_tfidf, valid_y)
print ("NB accuracy: ", accuracy)
```

However for an assignment I need something plotted on the x/y axis using matplotlib. I tried this:

```
m=linear_model.LogisticRegression()
m.fit(xtrain_tfidf, train_y)
y_pred = m.predict(xvalid_tfidf)
print(metrics.classification_report(valid_y, y_pred))
plt.plot(valid_y, y_pred)
plt.show()
```

But this gives me:

[image]

I need something that can more easily compare the accuracy of Naive Bayes vs SVM vs another algorithm. How can I do this?
Plotting classification report:

```
plt.plot(metrics.classification_report(valid_y, y_pred))
plt.show()
```

[image]

My classification output:

```
  precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      0.18      0.31        11
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00        14
           2       0.00      0.00      0.00        19
           3       0.50      0.77      0.61        66
           4       0.39      0.64      0.49        47
           5       0.00      0.00      0.00        23

    accuracy                           0.46       180
   macro avg       0.32      0.27      0.23       180
weighted avg       0.35      0.46      0.37       180
```

Error w edit:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(metrics.classification_report(valid_y, y_pred)).transpose()
```

gives error

> ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: Classification report is a table, and it is not meant to be plotted - try to run it first simply as `classification_report(valid_y, y_pred)` to see what it returns.

Comment: @desertnaut right. Dont necessarily need to use classification report here, however if I try to plot just that, I get nothing (see image in my update)

Comment: Can you post the output of `metrics.classification_report(valid_y, y_pred)`. If it's a table, you can just scatterplot both of the axes by passing `plt.scatter(x=..,y=..,..)`

Comment: @HirakSarkar yes - see my edit its a table

Comment: can you also print `metrics.classification_report(valid_y, y_pred).shape` ? The table seems to be truncated, it seems there are more than 4 columns, may be take it in a variable. 
```

df = metrics.classification_report(valid_y, y_pred)
print(df.shape)
print(df.columns)


```

Comment: @HirakSarkar I get the error - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: That means it's not a table, it's just a long string and not meant for plotting. Although you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200786/how-to-plot-scikit-learn-classification-report to get a heatmap. Hope this helps.
PS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34304414/4005668 this answer in specific.

Comment: @HirakSarkar ok, great. How can I see the non truncated string? or values past the first 5?

Comment: I expanded the comment in form of an answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

`metrics.classification_report` summarizes the prediction result. So this is not meant for plotting and just for printing a "report". If you want the table in a visual format you can follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/34304414/4005668.

Otherwise you can get the dataframe by capturing it in a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
# put it in a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(metrics.classification_report(..)).transpose()
# plot the dataframe
df.plot()
```

Comment: Right, however that answer is outdated and led to my secondary question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61705257/sklearn-plotting-classification-report-gives-a-different-output-than-basic-avg/61708658#61708658

Comment: Im getting an error plugging my own classification report into the dataframe.. see my edit..

Comment: Can you upload your a jupyter notebook or something so that I can reproduce the error? Because with my toyish examples it's not giving error.