# Sklearn - plotting classification report gives a different output than basic avg?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I wanted to leverage this answer [How to plot scikit learn classification report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200786/how-to-plot-scikit-learn-classification-report) turning an sklearn classification report into a heatmap.

It's all working with their sample report, however my classification report looks slightly different and is thus screwing up the functions.

Their report (notice the avg / total):

```
sampleClassificationReport =             
                   precision    recall  f1-score   support

          Acacia        0.62      1.00      0.76        66
          Blossom       0.93      0.93      0.93        40
          Camellia      0.59      0.97      0.73        67
          Daisy         0.47      0.92      0.62       272
          Echium        1.00      0.16      0.28       413

        avg / total     0.77      0.57      0.49       858
```

My report with `metrics.classification_report(valid_y, y_pred)` :

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      0.18      0.31        11
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00        14
           2       0.00      0.00      0.00        19
           3       0.50      0.77      0.61        66
           4       0.39      0.64      0.49        47
           5       0.00      0.00      0.00        23

    accuracy                           0.46       180
   macro avg       0.32      0.27      0.23       180
weighted avg       0.35      0.46      0.37       180
```

The issue, from the selected answer in the heatmap link, is here:

```
for line in lines[2 : (len(lines) - 2)]:
    t = line.strip().split()
    if len(t) < 2: continue
    classes.append(t[0])
    v = [float(x) for x in t[1: len(t) - 1]]
    support.append(int(t[-1]))
    class_names.append(t[0])
    print(v)
    plotMat.append(v)
```

Because I get the error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'avg'

So the problem truly is how my classification report is being outputted. What can I change here to match the sample?

EDIT: what Ive tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(metrics.classification_report(valid_y, y_pred)).T

df['support'] = df.support.apply(int)

df.style.background_gradient(cmap='viridis',
                             subset=pd.IndexSlice['0':'9', :'f1-score'])
```

Error:

> ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: The folks that answered that thread ~ 5 yrs ago obviously went to some painstakingly detailed parsing of the report output; but, as you can guess by comparing the two reports, scikit-learn has since then changed some of the report details, and that's why you cannot just plug their answer here.

Comment: @desertnaut right. thanks for following my struggling today lol.. to get their heat map to work, what would you suggest? is there a way to tweak their answer or must I find a new way to plot the classification metric?

Comment: There is probably a way, and it shouldn't be difficult - after all, the two classification reports are obviously not *that* different; but it really is not the kind of problem I'm good at - sorry :/

Answer (score 7):

With the advent of `output_dict` param in [`classification_report`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html), there is no hassle for parsing the report. You can directly use the output of classification report to be read as `pd.DataFrame`. Then, you could use the [`pd.Style`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Limitations) option to render the heat map.

Example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV


X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=30,
                           n_informative=12,
                           n_clusters_per_class=1, n_classes=10,
                           class_sep=2.0, random_state=42)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.3, stratify=y)


clf = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000, random_state=42).fit(X_train, y_train)



df = pd.DataFrame(classification_report(clf.predict(X_test), 
                                        y_test, digits=2,
                                        output_dict=True)).T

df['support'] = df.support.apply(int)

df.style.background_gradient(cmap='viridis',
                             subset=pd.IndexSlice['0':'9', :'f1-score'])
```

[image]

Comment: Great catch indeed ;)

Comment: Thank you.. but I think Im missing something. Copied your example and ran it, and compiled with no errors aside from having to correct LogisticsRegression to LogisticsRegressionCV, but the visuals dont show up? Where should they show?

Comment: See my edit.. plugging in my own classification report I get an error

Comment: U seems to have missed the 'output_dict' param. Can u try with that

Comment: Btw, can u try my example in jupyter notebook?