# Error "FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed" while preparing and visualizing classification report in scikit learn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I tried using code given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34304414) to visualize the classification report.

If I dont include labels for `classification_report()`, it works:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report 

y_test_1 = np.loadtxt('ytest1.txt')
y_pred_1 = np.loadtxt('ypred1.txt')
_classification_report = classification_report(y_test_1, y_pred_1)

_classification_report = "\n".join(list(_classification_report.split("\n")[i] for i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,15]))

plot_classification_report(_classification_report)
```

as can be seen in [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VW6jWOAJRCiKaJag9cNiUJq06ouUjCeb#scrollTo=3RI0TB2Y2uBw&line=1&uniqifier=1) colab notebook.

[image]
But if I include labels:

```
_categories=['blues', 'classical', 'country', 'disco', 'hiphop', 'jazz', 'metal', 'pop', 'reggae', 'rock']

y_test_1 = np.loadtxt('ytest1.txt')
y_pred_1 = np.loadtxt('ypred1.txt')
_classification_report = classification_report(y_test_1, y_pred_1, labels = _categories)

_classification_report = "\n".join(list(_classification_report.split("\n")[i] for i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,15]))

plot_classification_report(_classification_report)
```

it starts giving following error:

```
F:\ProgramFiles\python\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py:565: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  mask &= (ar1 != a)
F:\ProgramFiles\python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py:1221: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))
F:\ProgramFiles\python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py:1221: UndefinedMetricWarning: Recall and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no true samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))
F:\ProgramFiles\python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py:1221: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))
F:\ProgramFiles\python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py:1221: UndefinedMetricWarning: Recall and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no true samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))
```

I dont know there what is exact reason here. It could be one of two:

1. It might be because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46721064) bug in numpy.
2. My txt files contain numeric data, which is actually categories in the encoded format. For example, `blues` is 0, `classical` is 1 etc. Thats why it might be failing. In other models, where `y_test` and `y_pred` directly contains categories (as `str`) for each test data sample, it works:
   [image]
   I felt that its the order in which the labels are specified is what matters. But if thats not the case, do I have to explicitly convert back encoded numbers to categories? What is the standard approach?

You can find `ytest1.txt` and `ypred1.txt` [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nqfoxPb1uIkWaXr3bszGJ0U6f7ROL7xW?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong in thinking that the `labels` parameter of `classification_report` accepts labels to be displayed on graph, in the sense that I did not realise it performs filtering on the data. I felt that it simply put labels in the output image (as I felth docs a bit ambiguous about functionality of `labels`). Thinking that I might be wrong, I tried to convert the encoded labels to their original form.

I performed encoding as follows:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
y = #load data set...
y = encoder.fit_transform(y)
```

Using the same `encoder` object, I obtained orginal labels using its `inverse_transform()` method as follows:

```
if y_test.dtype == 'int32' or y_test.dtype == 'int64':
    _classification_report = classification_report(encoder.inverse_transform(y_test), encoder.inverse_transform(y_pred), labels=_categories)
```

Let me know if there is more standard approach.