# Drawing a grid in Python, with colors corresponding to different values

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid, draw, imshow

I'm attempting to draw a grid where for each value, a corresponding color is drawn. For instance:

```
[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],    
 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],    
 [1,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,1],    
 [1,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,1],    
 [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]
```

would appear as a 9x5 grid with a blue border (for 1), filled with black (for 0), with a 2x2 block of red at the bottom (for 2).

Apparently this can be done with `imshow` but I have no idea what the syntax would be.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391959/heatmap-in-matplotlib-with-pcolor) and note use can use `ax.pcolor` with a user-defined mapping of colors to values, so you can get your red, blue, black.

Answer (score 5):

One solution with matplotlib and NumPy:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def show_values(pc, fmt="%.2f", **kw):
    '''
    Heatmap with text in each cell with matplotlib's pyplot
    Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25074150/395857 
    By HYRY
    '''
    from itertools import izip
    pc.update_scalarmappable()
    ax = pc.get_axes()
    for p, color, value in izip(pc.get_paths(), pc.get_facecolors(), pc.get_array()):
        x, y = p.vertices[:-2, :].mean(0)
        if np.all(color[:3] > 0.5):
            color = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        else:
            color = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        ax.text(x, y, fmt % value, ha="center", va="center", color=color, **kw)

def cm2inch(*tupl):
    '''
    Specify figure size in centimeter in matplotlib
    Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22787457/395857
    By gns-ank
    '''
    inch = 2.54
    if type(tupl[0]) == tuple:
        return tuple(i/inch for i in tupl[0])
    else:
        return tuple(i/inch for i in tupl)

def heatmap(AUC, title, xlabel, ylabel, xticklabels, yticklabels):
    '''
    Inspired by:
    - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16124677/395857 
    - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25074150/395857
    '''

    # Plot it out
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()    
    c = ax.pcolor(AUC, edgecolors='k', linestyle= 'dashed', linewidths=0.2, cmap='YlOrRd', vmin=0.0, vmax=2.0)

    # put the major ticks at the middle of each cell
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(AUC.shape[0]) + 0.5, minor=False)
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(AUC.shape[1]) + 0.5, minor=False)

    # set tick labels
    #ax.set_xticklabels(np.arange(1,AUC.shape[1]+1), minor=False)
    ax.set_xticklabels(xticklabels, minor=False)
    ax.set_yticklabels(yticklabels, minor=False)

    # set title and x/y labels
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)      

    # Remove last blank column
    plt.xlim( (0, AUC.shape[1]) )

    # Turn off all the ticks
    ax = plt.gca()    
    for t in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
        t.tick1On = False
        t.tick2On = False
    for t in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
        t.tick1On = False
        t.tick2On = False

    # Add color bar
    plt.colorbar(c)

    # Add text in each cell 
    show_values(c)

    # resize 
    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig.set_size_inches(cm2inch(40, 20))



def main():
    data = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],    
                     [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],    
                     [1,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,1],    
                     [1,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,1],    
                     [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]])
    x_axis_size = data.shape[1]
    y_axis_size = data.shape[0]
    title = "Title"
    xlabel= "xlabel"
    ylabel="ylabel"
    xticklabels = range(1, x_axis_size+1) # could be text
    yticklabels = range(1, y_axis_size+1) # could be text   
    heatmap(data, title, xlabel, ylabel, xticklabels, yticklabels)
    plt.savefig('image_output.png', dpi=300, format='png', bbox_inches='tight') # use format='svg' or 'pdf' for vectorial pictures
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    #cProfile.run('main()') # if you want to do some profiling
```