# How do you improve matplotlib image quality?

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I am using a python program to produce some data, plotting the data using matplotlib.pyplot and then displaying the figure in a latex file.

I am currently saving the figure as a .png file but the image quality isn't great. I've tried changing the DPI in `matplotlib.pyplot.figure(dpi=200)` etc but this seems to make little difference. I've also tried using differnet image formats but they all look a little faded and not very sharp.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Why don't you use a vector graphics format like eps or pdf?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/332289/875127) deals with changing the size/dpi/resolution of an image, but it sounds like you've tried that. Check it out in-case there's something you missed.

Comment: You should definitely use a vector based format for plots. They are nicely supported by LaTeX.

Comment: Can you post a simple bit of code that generates a non-satisfactory image, and the file it generates?  Are you generating jpegs?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can save the images in a vector format so that they will be scalable without quality loss. Such formats are PDF and EPS. Just change the extension to `.pdf` or `.eps` and matplotlib will write the correct image format. Remember `LaTeX` likes EPS and `PDFLaTeX` likes PDF images. Although most modern LaTeX executables are PDFLaTeX in disguise and convert EPS files on the fly (same effect as if you included the `epstopdf` package in your preamble, which may not perform as well as you'd like).

Alternatively, increase the DPI, a lot. These are the numbers you should keep in mind:

- 300dpi: plain paper prints
- 600dpi: professional paper prints. Most commercial office printers reach this in their output.
- 1200dpi: professional poster/brochure grade quality.

I use these to adapt the quality of PNG figures in conjunction with `figure`'s `figsize` option, which allows for correctly scaled text and graphics as you improve the quality through dpi.

Comment: Thanks, .eps files produce much higher quality figures in lyx