# Matplotlib fullscreen not working

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying desperately to make a fullscreen plot in matplotlib on Ubuntu 12.10. I have tried everything I can find on the web. I need my plot to go completely fullscreen, not just maximized. Has anyone ever gotten this to work? If so, could you please share how?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib

Comment: MattDMo, that thread doesn't say anything about fullscreen. It simply says how to change the size of the figure. I need my plot to go truly fullscreen, meaning none of the system menus or icons are visible.

Comment: what happens if you set the size of the plot to the size of the screen? `matplotlib` isn't "aware" of your screen size, or what other decorations there are, like system menus etc. You're going to need to tie in to the window manager somehow if you want to override "always on top" values

Comment: Right, but I've read many times on the web that if you set the backend to "GTK" that you can enable fullscreen by pressing "f". Only problem is that I can't actually get it to work.

Comment: ***SOLVED***  I was on a previous version of matplotlib. I did the following. 1) Uninstalled python-matploblib from main Ubuntu software center. 2) ran "sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib" 3) ran "sudo pip install matplotlib 3) Changed the backend to "GTK" in my script 4) pressed "f" for fullscreen and it worked!

Comment: @Doughy Please answer your own question and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED** - My problem was that I was not up to the latest version of Matplotlib. I did the following steps to get fullscreen working in Matplotlib with Ubuntu 12.10.

1. Uninstalled matplotlib with `sudo apt-get remove python-matplotlib`
2. Installed build dependencies for matplotlib `sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib`
3. Installed matplotlib 1.2 with pip `sudo pip install matplotlib`
4. Set matplotlib to use the GTK backend with `matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = 'GTK'`
5. Used keyboard shortcut 'f' when the plot was onscreen and it worked!