# Matplotlib, changing figure size along with labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to save a figure with a given size.
While the size eventually changes, the labels and width of lines all remain intact.
I am using the following:

```
fig = plt.gcf()
mydpi = 100
fig.set_size_inches(470 / mydpi, 575 / mydpi)
fig.savefig('/tmp/fig.png')
```

How can I scale the image all together? Like when you do `fig.show()` and then scale it manually by mouse?

Comment: I'm not able to understand what you are looking for. Can you please add some output images of what you want ?

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at http://blog.olgabotvinnik.com/prettyplotlib/ . This might be more convenient.

Comment: Looks interesting, but the package author states that it is no longer maintained and recommends users to switch to `seaborn`. In addition, this post does not address the OP's question or how to solve it.

Comment: Yes you are right. The question might be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib) then