# How to place an external image on a figure with fixed, dpi-independent size?

Tags: python, matplotlib

As written in the question title, I want to be able to place an image on the figure with the images size given in inches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you change the size of figures drawn with matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib)

Comment: There are answers in that thread that directly address your need (and explain what you need to know).

Comment: No, why do say that? The question here is about adding an image to a matplotlib figure, not about the specific size of the figure itself. If you have took one second to look at my profile you see that i am not a total newcomer to matplotlib, while you don't seem to use it at all, so why discussing specifics with me?

Comment: So this gets now downvoted because people who don`t know matplotlib think the question is unclear *sight*?

Comment: my recommendation would be to put some example code (no matter how trivial it might be); this usually indicates some effort, and are less prone to receive downvotes. And just for the record; the question currently have *one* downvote (no upvotes).

Comment: Does figimage not work for you?  You'd have to resize the image according to the appropriate figure dpi manually first, but I'd think that would work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [figimage](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.figimage) will work for you?  You just have to account for the figure dpi and reshape your image accordingly.  I wrote a short placement routine that should size it right, using a `RectBiVariateSpline` for the interpolation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline

def place_img_on_fig(fig, img, size_inches):

    # Figure out the right size
    dpi = fig.dpi
    new_pxsize = [i * dpi for i in size_inches]

    # Interpolate to the right size
    spline = RectBivariateSpline(np.arange(img.shape[0]),
                                 np.arange(img.shape[1]),
                                 img)
    newx = np.arange(new_pxsize[0]) * (np.float(img.shape[0]) / new_pxsize[0])
    newy = np.arange(new_pxsize[1]) * (np.float(img.shape[1]) / new_pxsize[1])
    new_img = spline(newx, newy)

    # Call to figimage
    fig.figimage(new_img, cmap='jet')

# Make the figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,1), dpi=plt.rcParams['savefig.dpi'])

# Make a test image (100,100)
xx, yy = np.mgrid[0:100,0:100]
img = xx * yy

# Place the image
place_img_on_fig(fig, img, (0.5,4))

plt.show()
```

This places the 100x100 image on the figure like it is 0.5 inches high and 4 inches wide.  You can add offsets to the `figimage` call if you so desire.
[image: long thin image]

Comment: Thanks, i will test it later.