# How to change a figure's size in Python Seaborn package

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I'm having trouble increasing the size of my plot figures using Seaborn (imported as `sns`). I'm using `sns.pairplot` to plot columns of a data frame against one another.

```
    %matplotlib inline
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=10,10
    columns=list(df.columns.values)
    g=sns.pairplot(df, kind='reg', x_vars=columns,y_vars = ['Column 1'])
```

The plots populate with data just fine, but the figure size is too small.

I thought `plot.rCParams['figure.figsize']` would control how large the figure is, but it doesn't seem to take effect. I've tried a few different suggestions from online boards, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Did you try the `size` parameter in `pairplot`?

Comment: Tried setting size=5 in pairplot to make the images bigger but didn't seem to take effect. I think the problem is that seaborn is trying to place all 10 plots into a single row adjascent to one another, and that makes it too large for the screen unless the plots are shrunk down.  I was able to get this to work by plotting the data frame columns separately, but I figured seaborn would have a way to subplot the data frame columns onto different rows automatically without shrinking them down.

Comment: are you viewing these in a notebook? save them as images and i promise they'll be bigger with `size=5`

Comment: Do NOT use `size`. It's a deprecated parameter. Use `height` instead.

Answer (score 65):

sns.pairplot
"Returns the underlying PairGrid instance for further tweaking"
...for instance changing the figure size:

```
g=sns.pairplot(df, kind='reg', x_vars=columns,y_vars = ['Column 1'])
g.fig.set_size_inches(15,15)
```

Comment: Interesting this seems to shrink the size of the plot inside the window, but doesn't shrink the window itself. So i have this massive window now with empty space, and then a small figure in the bottom left.

What do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but doing that doesn't change anything for me... I can try `g.fig.set_size_inches(25,25)` or any other number but nothing will change... I tried with and without `%matplotlib inline`... not sure what is happening, any ideas?

Answer (score 25):

In addition to the [well working answer by @MartinAnderson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46346780/4124317), seaborn itself provides the option to set the height of the subplots of the grid. In combination with the `aspect` this determines the overall size of the figure in dependence of the number of subplots in the grid.

In seaborn <= 0.8.1:

```
g = sns.pairplot(..., size=10, aspect=0.6)
```

In seaborn >= 0.9.0:

```
g = sns.pairplot(..., height=10, aspect=0.6)
```

Note that this applies to all seaborn functions which generate a figure level grid, like 
`pairplot`, `relplot`,  `catplot`, `lmplot` and the underlying `PairGrid` or `FacetGrid`.

For other seaborn plots, which directly plot to axes, the solutions from [How do you change the size of figures drawn with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib) will work fine.

Comment: `size` is deprecated, use `height` instead.

Comment: @MERose Yes, indeed, that is what this answer is telling you.

Comment: `TypeError: bar() got multiple values for argument 'height'` when using the bottom one. sns version = 0.9.0

Comment: @Crispy13 Please read the answer completely. It says *"Note that this applies to all seaborn functions which generate a figure level grid,..."*

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm sorry.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. In a jupyter notebook, `sns.histplot` respects `figsize=(20,10)`, while `sns.displot` does not and requires something like `sns.displot(..., height=10, aspect=2)`. An oversight in the interface design?

Answer (score 21):

Try to put the size in parenthesis, this does the trick for me:

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=(10,10)
```

Comment: This does not necessarily work. Use the other answer instead.

Comment: Not OO interface

Answer (score 13):

If we would like to change only the height or only the width then you can do

```
g = sns.pairplot(df, kind='reg', x_vars=columns,y_vars = ['Column 1'])
g.fig.set_figheight(6)
g.fig.set_figwidth(10)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use set for style control : https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set.html

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(20,10)})
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26211115)

Answer (score 4):

Reffering to Rahul's question about sns.catplot ( [Unable to change the plot size with matplotlib and seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442910/unable-to-change-the-plot-size-with-matplotlib-and-seaborn) )

If you try in jupyter notebook:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(25,20))
sns.boxplot(x='CriticRating', y='AudienceRating', data=movies)
```

it is working, but

```
sns.boxplot(x='CriticRating', y='AudienceRating', data=movies)
plt.figure(figsize=(25,20))
```

is not working (plot is very small). It's important to add line `plt.figure(figsize=(25,20))` before `sns.boxplot()`and include `%matplotlib inline` of course in order to display plot in jupyter.

Comment: This answer works for `boxplot`, but not for any of the plots that create the figure itself like `pairplot` (this question) or `catplot` (the question you link to).

Answer (score 1):

You can use set for style control : https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set.html

We can accomplish this using `sns.set()` For example:

`sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(20,10)})`

Though, the preferred syntax is:

`sns.set_theme()`

NB: `sns.set()` or `sns.set_theme()` is a high level command that will set the (parameters) for everything else in your notebook.

`sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(20,10)})` will set this to be the figure size for everything else in your notebook