# Unable to change the plot size with matplotlib and seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, visualization, seaborn

As per the other answers provided in SO, I added `plt.figure(figsize=(25,25))` to my code which is straight forward.

```
sns.catplot(x="qualification", kind="count",hue="target", palette="ch:.25", data=raw_train)
plt.figure(figsize=(25,25))
```

but this just adds an additional plot index in the output rather than altering the size.

[image]

What is the right way of altering the figure size while using seaborn? I have tried the following, none of these worked.

- plt.figure(figsize=(25,25))
- fig.set_size_inches(11.7, 8.27)
- figure(num=None, figsize=(25, 25), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
- fig.set_figheight(25) & fig.set_figwidth(25)

**For the people who are marking it as duplicate, I have tried all the options mentioned in the link you guys provided. I have also listed the options I have tried.**

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46346780/4124317) from the duplicate works.

Comment: Catplot returns a facetgrid object. But you can set `height` and `aspect` as keyword arguments in the catplot function. This comes straight from the documentation btw. https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html

Comment: @HielkeWalinga This is the right answer. Thanks.