# How to change the figure size of a displot

Tags: python, seaborn

I am new to Seaborn, and I am having some trouble changing my figure size. I have looked at examples and adapted it to my code, but nothing seems to be happening.

When executing the code, my displot size does not change. Instead, a random plot just gets generated above my displot (which is really, really small).

I am really unsure on what I am doing wrong in terms of changing the size of my figures. Therefore, could someone kindly point me in the correct direction in order to achieve this?

Thanks!

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
```

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
sns.displot(data=df, x="column_name", kde=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the figure size for a seaborn plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594549/how-do-i-change-the-figure-size-for-a-seaborn-plot)

Answer (score 27):

[`seaborn.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) is a figure-level plot, which does not work with `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8), dpi=300)`

```
p = sns.displot(
    data=None,
    *,
    x=None,
    y=None,
    hue=None,
    row=None,
    col=None,
    weights=None,
    kind='hist',
    rug=False,
    rug_kws=None,
    log_scale=None,
    legend=True,
    palette=None,
    hue_order=None,
    hue_norm=None,
    color=None,
    col_wrap=None,
    row_order=None,
    col_order=None,
    ***height=5,**
    **aspect=1,***
    facet_kws=None,
    **kwargs,
)
```

by using `height` and `aspect` you can manage the size of it.

`dpi` can be adjusted with `p.fig.set_dpi(100)`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link help : [how to change figure size in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51443263/7309662)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
```