# Seaborn chart in Jupyter notebook ignoring figsize parameter

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

For some reason chart size remains unchanged, although I've changed figsize parameters.
Very appreciate your help :)

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dt = pd.DataFrame({'col':[26,0,23,7,23,23,22,23,19,22,1,1,11,11,23,14,23,21,11,23,10,11,13,28,18,25,23,28,18,23,18,18,
23,18,23,24,11,28,23,23,23,23,19,23,23,23,23,22,14]})


plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
sns.displot(dt['col'], kde=True)
plt.show()
```

[This is a result I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN6lm.jpg)

Comment: why didn't you use the height and aspect parameters?

Comment: distplot just makes a new figure for you.  Try: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 6)); sns.displot(dt['col'], kde=True, ax=ax);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try rewriting the code in this way:

```
g=sns.displot(dt['col'], kde=True)
g.fig.set_size_inches(15,6)
```

You can go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446029/how-to-change-a-figures-size-in-python-seaborn-package) for further information

Answer (score 1):

Try using the height parameter (in inches) and aspect (as the ratio of widht/height)

you want a figure with an aspect ratio of 2.67

```
ar = width / height 
ar = 16/6 
ar = 2.67
```

Try this line instead:

```
g=sns.displot(dt['col'], kde=True,height=6,aspect=2.67)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked this way! I wander why regular figsize not working in this case?