# Matplotlib yscale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have such plot. Could you advise me a approach how I can increase an y-axis's size in zooming part? I want make it (ylim[ymin, ymax]) bigger.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use 
     axes.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])
to choose your y zoom
More generally see http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/manual_axis.html
for a detailed example.

Comment: It is not what I want. Currenty y-axis's actual size in the screen is 1.5 cm. But my aim is to make it 3 cm or 4 cm.

Comment: Do you mean you have a problem with the ratio of the matplotlib screen size relative to the monitor size? If so, I think the figsize is addressed here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib