# How to set the size of a figure in Python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Could someone tell me, why the size of the figure generated by the code below is not as expected.

How can I modify this code to generate a picture with 100*400 pixels?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig  = plt.figure(figsize=(1,4),dpi=100,facecolor = 'red')
plt.show(fig)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: the picture generated by this code have 218*409 pixels, and I don't konw why?

Comment: Good point. I tried (very small changes to your code) and got 100dpi and 120x398 pixels. Size is in inches and dpi is dots per inch, so you should get 100 x 400.

Comment: But see this page: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib` So this is a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the dpi during `savefig`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig  = plt.figure(figsize=(1,4),facecolor = 'red', dpi=100)
plt.savefig('test.png', dpi=100)

plt.show(fig)
```

Of course, it wont be perfect, but will be close ..