# Create a bigger graphic with Python and Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm a newbie and I would like to change the size of the bar chart I created with Matplotlib and Python, so I can show it in a presentation. I have very much values and the outcoming graphic is far too small.
The columns 'State' and 'Hospital 30-Day Readmission Rates from Pneumonia' contain >50 values.

This is my current code:

```
smallgroup.plot('State', 'Hospital 30-Day Readmission Rates from Pneumonia', kind='bar')
plt.title("Hospital 30-Day Readmission Rates from Pneumonia")
plt.xlabel("States")
plt.ylabel("Readmission Rates")
plt.savefig('readmission_rate_pneumonia.png');
```

Comment: Do you want to change the size of the entire figure? Try setting `figsize` if so. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

using width of bar plot :

```
bar(x, y, width=30)
```

see example here :

https://plot.ly/matplotlib/bar-charts/

Comment: It doesn't work. The bar chart is still 432x288 px and the bars are now too big to deifne. With the current px size I have to use a width < 0.5. But this doesn't change the size of the whole graphic. I need a bigger picture.

Comment: you should adjust your figure size to your bar size...here information about figure : https://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html