# How to increase the physical size of axes in matplotlib pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting the following graph,
[image: Graph plotted]

I would like to change the physical size of the axes. I have plotted the xticks in hopes of being able to increase the spacing between them and thus increase the physical size of the axes, but no luck. I want a resulting image, that is possibly very large, but when zoomed in, I am able to see individual points and the arrows plotted. I tried changing the size of the figure, but it just creates a larger image, with higher resolution, and same level of detail as before, it does not allow me to see more points when I zoom in.

Can someone please tell me how can I increase the physical size of the axes so when I zoom in on the saved image (right now I'm saving it in a pdf format) I can see individual points? Thanks so much

Comment: The figure size and the zooming are a priori unrelated. It is therefore not really clear what the problem is you are trying to solve and need help with.  I would suggest you explain it in much more detail, very accurately distinguishing between things you observe and things you want to observe.

Comment: Hi Anny, I'm having the same problem. You might find this answer helpful which interestingly is from @ImportanceOfBeingErnest https://stackoverflow.com/a/44864135/4906855

Comment: @NickleDave I still don't understand the problem that is asked about here. But if you do understand it, you may try to reword the question to be more understandable. Also if you feel that it is a duplicate of the other question, you may mark as such.

Answer (score 6):

You could try `plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))` in order to increase the width of the figure. It should be possible to obtain a suitable ratio of height and width by playing with these numbers (20=width, 10=height). There is a similar question here: [How do you change the size of figures drawn with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib)