# Overlapping/crowded labels on y-axis python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning, random-forest, scrum

I'am kind of in a rush to finish this for tomorrows presentation towards the project owner. We are a small group of economic students in germany trying to figure out machine learning with python. We set up a Random Forest Classifier and are desperate to show the estimators important features in a neat plot. By applying google search we came up with the following solution that kind of does the trick, but leaves us unsatisfied due to the overlapping of the labels on the y-axis. The code we used looks like this:

```
feature_importances = clf.best_estimator_.feature_importances_
feature_importances = 100 * (feature_importances / feature_importances.max())
sorted_idx = np.argsort(feature_importances)

pos = np.arange(sorted_idx.shape[0])
plt.barh(pos, feature_importances[sorted_idx], align='center', height=0.8)
plt.yticks(pos, df_year_four.columns[sorted_idx])
plt.show()
```

Due to privacy let me say this: The feature names on the y-axis are overlapping (there are about 30 of them). I was looking into the documentation of matplotlib in order to get an understanding of how to do this by myself, unfortunately I couldn't find anything helpful. Seems like training and testing models is easier than understanding matplotlib and creating plots :D

Thank you so much for helping out and taking the time, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your solution, and I want to just add this link here to explain why: [How to change spacing between ticks in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863375/how-to-change-spacing-between-ticks-in-matplotlib)

> The spacing between ticklabels is exclusively determined by the space between ticks on the axes. Therefore the only way to obtain more space between given ticklabels is to make the axes larger.

The question I linked shows that by making the graph large enough, your axis labels would naturally be spaced better.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `np.argsort` that will return a numpy array with many indices. And you are using that array as labels for your Y-Axis thus there is overlapping of labels.

My suggestion will be to use an index for **sorted_idx** like,

`plt.yticks(pos, df_year_four.columns[sorted_idx[0]])`

This will plot only for 1 label.

Answer (score 0):

Got it guys! 
'Geistesblitz' as we say in germany! (spiritual lightening)
See the variable `feature_importances` in the third top row? Add `feature_importnaces[:-15]`
to view only the top half of the features and loosen up the y-axis. Yes!!! This does well because there are way less important features.