# increase space among number in X axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have the following plot:

[image]

How can I increase the space among values in X axis with matplotlib?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share a code snippet that we can reproduce the plot?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863375/how-to-change-spacing-between-ticks-in-matplotlib

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change spacing between ticks in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863375/how-to-change-spacing-between-ticks-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a log scale and invert the x-axis:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

x = [round(28800 * 2 ** (-i)) for i in range(10)]
y = np.random.randint(0, 80, len(x))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
ax.invert_xaxis()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Was this answer helpful?