# Increase width between ticks for barplot matplotlib

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I realize this might be a duplicate of other questions on here but I am completely stumped. I currently have this:
[image]

I am trying to increase the space between the labels so they are readable.

I have tried many suggestions that I found however none of them seem to be able to help. Here is what I currently have:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


corr_df = pd.read_csv("country_corr_202112030124.csv")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(40,3))

x = (range(corr_df['country_code'].size))
new_x = [2*i for i in x]

plt.bar(new_x,corr_df['temp_co2_corr_cof'], align='center', width=0.8)
plt.xticks([i*2 for i in range(corr_df['country_code'].size)], corr_df['country_code'])


# ax.set_xticks(corr_df['country_code'])
# ax.set_xticklabels(corr_df['country_code'], fontsize=8)
ax.set_xticklabels(corr_df['country_code'], rotation=90)

plt.show()
```

Data csv can be found [here](https://github.com/Krish-Khatri/datadump/blob/main/country_corr_202112030124.csv)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change spacing between ticks in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863375/how-to-change-spacing-between-ticks-in-matplotlib)

Comment: No, it does not fix the error. I have seen this link.