# How to reduce the space between the x-ticks in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863375/how-to-change-spacing-between-ticks) but the answers did not help.

I have the following code that generates 4 plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

group_x = [5, 0, 1, 16, 3, 1, 2, 0, 8, 2, 11, 5]
group_y = [8, 10, 6, 0, 0, 5, 12, 0, 14, 2, 1, 7]
group_w = [1, 3, 13, 9, 0, 15, 6, 2, 3, 7, 1, 0]
group_z = [0, 1, 2, 0, 10, 12, 12, 0, 8, 12, 4, 6]
ranges = ['a', '(a, b)', '(b, c)', '(c, d)', '(d, e)', '(e, f)',
          '(f, g)', '(g, h)', '(h, i)', '(i, j)', '(j, k)', 'k']

colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple']
participants = ['Group X', 'Group Y', 'Group W', 'Group Z']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12, 5))
c = 0
for i, ax_row in enumerate(axes):
    for j, ax in enumerate(ax_row):
        data = [group_x, group_y, group_w, group_z][c]
        ax.text(.5, .9, f'{participants[i]}',
                horizontalalignment='center',
                transform=ax.transAxes)

        bars = ax.bar(ranges, data, color=colors[c], width=0.2)
        ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 21, 5))
        ax.set_yticklabels(range(0, 21, 5), fontsize=9)
        ax.set_xticks(np.arange(12))
        ax.set_xticklabels(ranges, rotation=30, ha='right', fontsize=8.5)
        ax.set_xlabel('Characters')
        ax.set_ylabel('Frequency', fontsize=8)
        for bar, score in zip(bars, data):
            ax.text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2, bar.get_height(), str(score), ha='center', va='bottom')
        c += 1
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('stackover.png', dpi=600, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

The output is:

[image]

I want to reduce the space between the x-axis ticks so that the bars and their corresponding x-ticks will be very close next to each other. Also, I want the `a` bar to be very close to the y-axis and reduce the space between the `k` bar and the right edge of the corresponding frame. How do I change my code to have the mentioned effects?

Comment: What should it actually look like with this reduced space?!  The only suggestion I could have would be to make the figure less wide which would decrease the gaps.   Or maybe you mean make the bars wider, but then the ticks would stay the same distance.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your problem consists of two steps:

1. adjust the `width` parameter of `ax.bar`, e.g., set it to 1 (bars touch each other) or 0.95 (a little bit of space between them)
2. adjust the x-limit of the horizontal axis so that the bars are closer to the y-axis.

Here are just the two lines that need to be changed:

```py
for i, ...
   for j, ...
        # ...
        bars = ax.bar(ranges, data, color=colors[c], width=0.95)
        # ...
        ax.set_ylabel('Frequency', fontsize=8)
        ax.set_xlim(-0.6, len(ranges) - 0.4)
```

And this is the result:

[image]

For the bar plot, each bar is located at an integer x-value. The first is at "x=0" with a width of  approximately 1. Therefore, the left side is at ~-0.5 and the right one at ~0.5 (I said "approximately 1" because this depends on the width parameter of the bar plot).

**P.S.:** In cases like yours, it might be helpful for the reader of a diagram if you remove some redundant ticklabels and axis labels. E.g. by using

```py
axes[0,0].set(xticklabels=[], xlabel="")
axes[0,1].set(xticklabels=[], xlabel="", yticklabels=[], ylabel='')
axes[1,1].set(yticklabels=[], ylabel='')
```

just before `plt.tight_layout()` it becomes directly clear to the reader that, e.g., the x-axis of the subplots in columns are the same.

**PPS.:** There is a good reason to set `width=0.95` and to leave a bit of space: in doing so you make it clear that this is not a histogram but a bar plot. The values in a histogram cover a whole range without empty spots and can be summed while this does not make sense in your case where you use categorical data.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but as Sam Mason stated, you can either:

Increase bars width:

```
bars = ax.bar(ranges, data, color=colors[c], width=1)
```

[image]

Reduce figsize:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(9, 5))
```

[image]

Or a combination of both. You can iterate numbers until you find what best adapts to your need.
[image]

If in other case you are looking for something different, it would help to clarify what you want. I hope it helps.