# MatplotLib 'saveFig()' Fullscreen

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I used MatplotLib with Cartopy to generate some data images.
The problem is that when I set the frame size to fullscreen and use plt.show() the image is perfect and the resolution is fine.

However, when I save this figure using 'plt.savefig()' the image saved keeps with its original size (not fullscreen).

Showing outcome images:

[image: Showing the image - not saving it]

[image: Saving the image - not showing it]

My code is the following:

def plot_tec_cartopy(descfile):
    global matrixLon, matrixLat, matrixTec

```
ax = plt.axes(projection=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())

v = np.linspace(0, 80, 46, endpoint=True)
cp = plt.contourf(matrixLon, matrixLat, matrixTec, v, cmap=plt.cm.rainbow)
plt.clim(0, 80)
plt.colorbar(cp)

ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle=':')
ax.set_extent([-85, -30, -60, 15])

# Setting X and Y labels using LON/LAT format
ax.set_xticks([-85, -75, -65, -55, -45, -35])
ax.set_yticks([-60, -55, -50, -45, -40, -35, -30, -25, -20, -15, -10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15])
lon_formatter = LongitudeFormatter(number_format='.0f',
                                   degree_symbol='',
                                   dateline_direction_label=True)
lat_formatter = LatitudeFormatter(number_format='.0f',
                                  degree_symbol='')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)

plt.title('Conteúdo Eletrônico Total', style='normal', fontsize='12')

# Acquiring Date
year, julianday = check_for_zero(descfile.split('.')[2]), descfile.split('.')[3]
hour, minute = descfile.split('.')[4], descfile.split('.')[5].replace('h','')
date = datetime.datetime(int(year), 1, 1, int(hour), int(minute)) + datetime.timedelta(int(julianday)-1)
month = date.month
day = date.day

# Set common labels
ax.text(1.22, 1.05, 'TEC', style='normal',
    verticalalignment='top', horizontalalignment='right',
    transform=ax.transAxes,
    color='black', fontsize=11)
ax.text(1, 0.005, 'EMBRACE/INPE', style='italic',
    verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='right',
    transform=ax.transAxes,
    color='black', fontsize=10)
ax.text(1, 0.995, str(date) + ' UT', style='italic',
    verticalalignment='top', horizontalalignment='right',
    transform=ax.transAxes,
    color='black', fontsize=10)
ax.text(0.5, -0.08, 'Copyright \N{COPYRIGHT SIGN} 2017 INPE - Instituto Nacional de',
    style='oblique', transform=ax.transAxes,
    verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='center',
    color='black', fontsize=8)
ax.text(0.5, -0.108, 'Pesquisas Espacias. Todos direitos reservados',
    style='oblique', transform=ax.transAxes,
    verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='center',
    color='black', fontsize=8)

manager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
manager.resize(*manager.window.maxsize())

figName = 'tec.map' + '.' + str(year) + '.' + str(julianday) + '.' + str(hour) + '.' + str(minute) + 'h.png'
#plt.show()
plt.savefig(figName, dpi=500)
plt.clf()
```

Maybe I need to set some parameter into savefig() to say it that it needs to save my modified frame? Can someone help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let me guess, MATLAB user who expects the figure on screen to be somehow related to the figure in the file?

Comment: Helpful, but I don't consider it a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4306340/2988730. I'm drafting you an answer right now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Coming from MATLAB, it is not intuitive that your displayed figure does not have to affect the saved one in terms of dimensions, etc. Each one is handled by a different backend, and you can modify the `dpi` and `size_inches` as you choose.

Increasing the DPI is definitely going to help you get a large figure, especially with a format like PNG, which does not know about the size in inches. However, it will not help you scale the text relative to the figure itself.

To do that, you will have to use the object oriented API, specifically, [`figure.set_size_inches`](https://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_size_inches), which I don't think has an equivalent in `plt`. Replace

```
plt.savefig(figName, dpi=500)
```

with

```
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches((8.5, 11), forward=False)
fig.savefig(figName, dpi=500)
```

The size `8.5, 11` is the width and height of the standard paper size in the US, respectively. You can set it to whatever you want. For example, you can use your screen size, but in that case be sure to get the DPI right as well.

Comment: Your solution is great and solved the problem! 
Thanks for your answer, Mad Physicist. :)

Comment: @Hollweg you may not have enough reputation to upvote an answer, but you can always accept the answers that are good and useful for you. Accepting an answer to your question also removing your question from the `unanswered` list as it should be.

Comment: why do I got this error? AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: @Lei. Is it `savefig` or something in the new version?

Comment: @MadPhysicist for me `fig.savefig(...)` solved the AttributeError.

Comment: @Shai. Looks like they made the name consistent between the Figure class and pyplot in later versions. Thanks for checking.

Comment: @MadPhysicist would you consider edit your answer accordingly?

Comment: @Shai. I made the update. Change was pre-1.5. This is a pretty old answer I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some context on @Mad Physicist answer. If someone is trying to use it with a new version of matplotlib, you will get an AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'save'. You also need to be careful about when you call `plt.show()` otherwise you will get a blank image. You need to update the code as follow:

```py
# Create a plot
plt.barh(range(top), imp, align='center')
plt.yticks(range(top), names)

# Get the current figure like in MATLAB
fig = plt.gcf()
plt.show() # show it here (important, if done before you will get blank picture)
fig.set_size_inches((8.5, 11), forward=False)
fig.savefig(figName, dpi=500) # Change is over here
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I tried all answers above, and didn't seem to solve my problem. Maybe becase I run on Mac, but I figured it out, free to try.

```py
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

"""work on macos"""


def test():
    x = list(range(10))
    y = list(range(10))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x, y, linewidth=1.0)

    mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
    mng.resize(*mng.window.maxsize())
    figure = plt.gcf()
    plt.show()
    figure.savefig('test.png')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Comment: i got next error: 'FigureManagerBase' object has no attribute 'window'

Comment: still works for me, did you change anything of the code?