# Problems with setting aspect ratio in matplotlib, python 3.6, flattening figure

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to format a figure I am making. I have been trying to set the aspect ratio, but whenever I include the aspect ratio call, or use ax.set_aspect(), I end up with a flattened figure.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = 'Calibri'

ax.set(xlim=[415, 700], ylim=[0,1.01], aspect=1)

ax.set_xlabel('Wavelength (nm)')
ax.set_ylabel('Normalized Reflectance (a.u.)')

_ = ax.plot(x_lambda[0], y_refl_norm[0], marker='', linestyle='-', color='m')
_ = ax.plot(x_lambda[1], y_refl_norm[1], marker='', linestyle='-', color='b')
_ = ax.plot(x_lambda[2], y_refl_norm[2], marker='', linestyle='-', color='c')
_ = ax.plot(x_lambda[3], y_refl_norm[3], marker='', linestyle='-', color='g')
_ = ax.plot(x_lambda[4], y_refl_norm[4], marker='', linestyle='-', color='y')
_ = ax.plot(x_lambda[5], y_refl_norm[5], marker='', linestyle='-', 
color='orange')
_ = ax.plot(x_lambda[6], y_refl_norm[6], marker='', linestyle='-', color='r')

ax.legend(('30 degrees', '35 degrees', '40 degrees', '45 degrees', '50 
degrees', '55 degrees', '60 degrees'), loc='lower left', fontsize='x-small',
frameon='True', facecolor='navajowhite', framealpha=0.95)
```

[Without the "aspect=1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCcxG.png)

[With the "aspect=1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTzXu.png)

Answer (score 1):

What else would you expect if the range of your x-axis is ~300x larger than the range on the y-axis? With `aspect=1` this gives you a figure of which the height is ~300x smaller than the width.

Take this simple example:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

pl.figure()
pl.subplot(231, aspect=1)
pl.fill_between([0,1],[0,0],[1,1])
pl.xlim(0,10)
pl.ylim(0,10)

pl.subplot(232, aspect=1)
pl.fill_between([0,1],[0,0],[1,1])
pl.xlim(0,10)
pl.ylim(0,5)

pl.subplot(233, aspect=1)
pl.fill_between([0,1],[0,0],[1,1])
pl.xlim(0,10)
pl.ylim(0,1)

pl.subplot(234)
pl.fill_between([0,1],[0,0],[1,1])
pl.xlim(0,10)
pl.ylim(0,10)

pl.subplot(235)
pl.fill_between([0,1],[0,0],[1,1])
pl.xlim(0,10)
pl.ylim(0,5)

pl.subplot(236)
pl.fill_between([0,1],[0,0],[1,1])
pl.xlim(0,10)
pl.ylim(0,1)
```

When the x-range is equal to the y-range you end up with a square figure in order to keep the aspect ratio of the x-to-y axis equal (black block = square). If the y-range is half the x-range, the height will be half the width, again to keep the aspect ratio equal.

In your case, the only solution is to use an aspect ratio unequal to one, unless you want to make a veeeeeery wide figure in order to keep the y-axis readable.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I guess I really misunderstood what "aspect=1" meant, but that makes much more sense that it is the aspect of the data rather than the aspect ratio of the printed figure.

Comment: err aspect ratio of the axes*

Comment: It is quite easy to set the aspect ratio of the figure, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib