# python matplotlib plot scaling xaxis and labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

my output is kinda messy. I want the states on the x-axis to be visible

```
performance0 = denied_states['STATE'].value_counts().sort_index()
performance1 = certified_states['STATE'].value_counts().sort_index() 
performance2 = cw_states['STATE'].value_counts().sort_index()
performance3 = w_states['STATE'].value_counts().sort_index()
plt.plot( performance0, label = 'Denied')
plt.plot( performance1, label = 'Certified')
plt.plot( performance2, label = 'Certified-Withdrawn')
plt.plot( performance3, label = 'Withdrawn')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('States')

plt.ylabel('Applications')
plt.title('No. of Applicants status of H1B Visa based on states')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: output graph]

Answer (score 0):

1. Syntax for setting the [`xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) is:

   ```
   xticks(locs, [labels], **kwargs)  # Set locations and label
   ```

   `**kwargs` may contain [Text properties](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text), among them the `fontproperties` keyword to which you may assign a [`FontProperties`](https://matplotlib.org/api/font_manager_api.html#matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties) object.

   So you could try something like:

   ```
   fp = matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(family="sans-serif", size=8)  # play around with the formatting
   plt.xticks(rotation=90, fontproperties=fp)
   ```
2. Another possibility would be to increase the size of the whole plot which is described in: [How do you change the size of figures drawn with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib)