# How to increase image size of pandas.DataFrame.plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How can I modify the size of the output image of the function `pandas.DataFrame.plot`?

I tried:

`plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))`

and

`%matplotlib notebook`

but none of them work.

Comment: Already answered in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39770939/7758804) of the duplicate on **Sep 29 '16**

Comment: (This question is currently the subject of a [meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412672/).)

Answer (score 277):

Try the `figsize` parameter in `df.plot(figsize=(width,height))`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2],"b":[1,2]})
df.plot(figsize=(3,3));
```

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2],"b":[1,2]})
df.plot(figsize=(5,3));
```

[image]

The size in `figsize=(5,3)` is given in `inches` per `(width, height)`.

An alternative way is to set desired `figsize` at the top of the Jupyter Notebook, *prior* to plotting:

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10, 5)
```

This change will affect all the plots, following this statement.

---

As per explanation why it doesn't work for the OP:

> `plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))` doesn't work because `df.plot()` creates its own `matplotlib.axes.Axes` object, the size of which cannot be changed *after* the object has been created. For details please see the [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L619) code.
> Though, one can change *default* `figsize` *prior* to creation, by changing default figsize with `plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (width, height)`

Answer (score 28):

If you want to make a change to the whole notebook global:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [10, 5]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib as plt
```

After importing the file we can use the Matplotlib library, but remember to use it as plt:

```
df.plt(kind='line', figsize=(10, 5))
```

After that, the plot will be done and the size increased.
In figsize, the 10 is for breadth and 5 is for height.
Also other attributes can be added to the plot too.

Comment: This is a terrible answer, which results in `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'plt'`. `pandas` imports `matplotlib` as a dependency, and the correct way to use `pandas.DataFrame.plot` to adjust `figsize` is shown in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51174822/7758804). `kind='line'` is not required, because it is the default. As the answer is blatantly incorrect, the fact it has any upvotes undermines the credibility of voting system. The correct import is `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` as shown in the matplotlib Usage Guide.

Comment: `import matplotlib as mpl` where `mpl` is the correct alias, not `plt`. [matplotlib Usage Guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#splitting-lines-into-smaller-chunks)