# How do I plot top 10 Cities with highest life expectancy rate

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I have a dataframe and it has few columns.
I want to plot the top 10 countries with highest life expectancy rate.
Here is my dataset
[image]

It should be in matplotlib or seaborn.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) with [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
(df.nlargest(10, 'Life expectancy(years)(Country)')
   .plot.bar(x='City', y='Life expectancy(years)(Country)'))
```

For seaborn use [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(x='City', 
            y='Life expectancy(years)(Country)',
            data=df.nlargest(10, 'Life expectancy(years)(Country)'))
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. How can we increase the size of graph or plot in sns.barplot

Comment: @MalikHamza - yes, you can do it, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174691/how-to-increase-image-size-of-pandas-dataframe-plot)

Comment: @MalikHamza - and for seaborn use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594549/how-to-change-the-figure-size-of-a-seaborn-axes-or-figure-level-plot)