# plt.figure() is not changing size of double bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make the double bar chart dimensions bigger with figsize but my code doesn't seem to work.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,4))
MM_coh_chart = MM_coh.set_index('Snapshot_Date').plot(kind='bar', width=0.8, stacked=False, color=['red', 'steelblue'])
plt.legend(title='MPM Active Cohort vs Cohort Size', labels=['Cohort Currently Active', 'Cohort Size'], bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0)
plt.show(MM_coh_chart)
```

Comment: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 4))`, `MM_coh.set_index('Snapshot_Date').plot(kind='bar', width=0.8, stacked=False, color=['red', 'steelblue'], ax=ax)`, `ax.legend(...)`.

Comment: Or `MM_coh.set_index('Snapshot_Date').plot(..., figsize=(15,4))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase image size of pandas.DataFrame.plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174691/how-to-increase-image-size-of-pandas-dataframe-plot)

Answer (score 0):

My go to is to use `plt.rcParams` as it changes the figure size for all downstream graphs without having to define it each time. Something like:

```py
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,10)
```

... at the top of your code has always worked for me.