# How to plot this 3d Axes matplotlib with earth map plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, matplotlib-basemap

I have plotted axis 3d using plot_trisurf but i am not able to plot this with

[image]

earth map /basemap. 
some of the questions:

1. How i can plot same figure as above in Map in 3d?
2. How i can increase my figure size? fig.size(8,6) function is not 
      working .

Comment: Basemap does not work for 3D. To change the figure size see [How do you change the size of figures drawn with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib)

Comment: i have tried above suggestion for figure size but it is not working.

Comment: Then how to plot map for 3D ?

Comment: Have a look at the gallery: https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html

Comment: nothing found in gallery :(