# Displaying images at full size in Jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I try to display images inside a Jupyter notebook. To do that, I use a code like the following one:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for N in [20, 100, 300]:
  x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(1,N,N), np.linspace(1,N,N))
  img = (x+y) % 2
  plt.figure()
  plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
  plt.title("Image shape: " + str(img.shape));
```

I obtain the images below:

[image: big squares]
[image: meddium squares]
[image: small squares]

As you can see, the images are not properly displayed because they are resized so as to have the same size on the screen. Therefore, the images are interpolated (to the nearest neighbors), creating unwanted aliasing. This is too bad for image processing...

I tried to define `figsize` and `dpi` in `figure`, but that not works.

Comment: If you are using Jupyter lab double click on the plot cell to view it with given figure size.

Comment: It does not work. In addition, I would have them to be automatically well displayed.

Comment: What exactly does not work when using `figsize` and `dpi` in `figure`?

Comment: For example, if I set `figsize` to the image size in pixels (obtained with `img.shape`) divided by the DPI value (obtained with `fig.dpi` where `fig = plt.figure()`), then, I obtain an image with approximately the good size, but not exactly... see https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/miv.u-strasbg.fr/mazet/test4.ipynb

Comment: Correct. This is due to the spacings around the axes. You may set them to 0 via `fig.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1)` (this works well in a jupyter notebook), or you can account for them and make the figure larger by the amount of spacing you want.

Comment: This still does not work: the images have not the correct size, this can easily be seen because of the aliasing effect...

Comment: Feel free to provide a [mcve] of the attempted solution.  (and use the @username notation to ping people in the comments)

Comment: @Vinz Did you end up solving this

Comment: Not at all! I did not find any solution to this. With Matlab however, it is easy to display an image at its actual size (ie one pixel in the matrix *is* one pixel on screen).

Answer (score 2):

I used this & it worked:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (width,height)
```

*(Here width & height are in inches*)

For more detail, you can have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib)

Comment: Thanks Mam, this is something I was looking for.