# Black bar covering my x labels for matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to play a figure and I am having a black box pop up on the bottom of the plot where the x labels should be. I tried this command from a similar question on here in the past:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})
```

But the problem was still the same. Here is my current code:

```
import pylab
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})

df['date'] =  df['date'].astype('str') 

pos = np.arange(len(df['date']))
plt.bar(pos,df['value'])
ticks = plt.xticks(pos, df['value'])
```

And my plot is attached here. Any help would be great!
[image]

Comment: It is not a black bar but actual `df['value']` from your dataframe. It looks like a black bar because your dataframe has over 100s of values probably, all of which are written one over the other as x-tick labels.

Comment: @Bazingaa Ahh I see. Those are all dates that I am trying to have labeled in the x axis and some quantitative value in the y. It seems as if the Y axis is okay but is there any way to reformat the x axis to accommodate all the labels?

Comment: Increasing the size of the plot could help, but you may need to make it very big before the problem goes away.  I would suggest there might be a better way to display the information that you're looking for - you shouldn't need X ticks for every single data value.

Comment: @Apollys Can you possibly guide me as to how to do this? I am quite new using matplotlib and a lot of the syntax is quite new to me.

Comment: To change your figure size: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib

Comment: @Apollys Thanks for the link. Does matplotlib have any sort of auto resize feature in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pos = np.arange(len(df['date']))` and `ticks = plt.xticks(pos, df['value'])` are causing the problem you are having.  You are putting an xtick at *every* value you have in the data frame.

Don't know how you data looks like and what's the most sensible way to do this.  `ticks = plt.xticks(pos[::20], df['value'].values[::20], rotation=90)` will put a tick every 20 rows that would make the plot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

It actually is not a black bar, but rather all of your x-axis labels being crammed into too small of a space. You can try rotating the axis labels to create more space or just remove them all together.

Comment: I wouldn’t put this as an answer but as a comment

Answer (score 0):

matplotlib expects proper data type (either date/numerical) when it created x ticks on x axis.
If we pass string type x-values.It will try to keep all possible string values on x axis thus will form a black bar where each value is over written on another.

To over come convert df['date'] to datetime dtype using to_datetime.
and remove this
`df['date'] =  df['date'].astype('str')`