# Making a figure longer in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a dataframe with one column and 80 rows, and I want to visualize it as a horizontal bar chart. I use pandas `plot()` function like this:

```
df.plot(kind='barh')
plt.show()
```

But, because my dataframe has too many rows, the result is
[image]

How I can make the figure longer? Becasue I think if the figure becomes longer, all the row information will fit into the vertical axis.

Comment: Have you tried the previous SO question? [How to change the size of figures in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib)

Comment: you can use `ax.set_position`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use figsize parameter of plot function

> figsize=(length, height)

```
df.plot(figsize=(20,20), kind='barh')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Give the figure more height:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
ax.plot(kind='barh')
plt.show()
```