# Space between label in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

here is a simple code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = []
y = []

dict_plot = {}

dictResult = {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14, 15: 15, 16: 16, 17: 17, 18: 18, 19: 19, 20: 20, 21: 21, 22: 22, 23: 23, 24: 24, 25: 25, 26: 26, 27: 27, 28: 28, 29: 29, 30: 30, 31: 31, 32: 32, 33: 33, 34: 34, 35: 35, 36: 36, 37: 37, 38: 38, 39: 39, 40: 40, 41: 41, 42: 42, 43: 43, 44: 44, 45: 45, 46: 46, 47: 47, 48: 48, 49: 49, 50: 50, 51: 51, 52: 52, 53: 53, 54: 54, 55: 55, 56: 56, 57: 57, 58: 58, 59: 59, 60: 60, 61: 61, 62: 62, 63: 63, 64: 64, 65: 65, 66: 66, 67: 67}


i = 0
for key in dictResult.keys():
    x.append(dictResult[key])
    y.append("toto_"+str(i))
    i = i +1


plt.xlabel("Nb video by category")
plt.ylabel("Category")
plt.title("Nb Video")
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.savefig("catnbvideo.png", bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

but the result is awful :

[image: Awful plot]

If you have any ideas on how to add space between the Y label.

regards

Comment: Your code doesn't work, please fix it to make it a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: I'm sorry, but even like this it's not properly working: you're trying to plot x and y, but y is only a label....

Comment: You have a few options, including: make font smaller, make axis longer, label less points. It's really up to you what makes most sense.

Comment: Are you sure you want to plot categoricals here? Why not plot numbers instead? That would give you nicely separated values on the axes.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for [yticks](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html). You need to make sure that tick values are distance enough from each other that they don't cramp together. Tick values and labels could be different, so you can say `yticks([0, 5, 10], labels = [0, 1, 2])`. Also, make sure to [change your plot size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib) as well, if you have a lot of values, you need more space anyway. You can change that by creating a `fig` and `ax`.