# Using the amount of bars to set the width/labelsize of a bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am pretty new to using Matplotlib

I couldn't figure out how to apply the things I found to my own graph, so I decided to make my own post

I use this code to generate my bar chart:

```
p = (len(dfrapport.index))

p1 = p * 2.5
p2 = p * 1.5

height = dfrapport['aantal']
bars = dfrapport['soort']
y_pos = np.arange(len(bars))


plt.bar(y_pos, height, color = ['black', 'red','orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan'])

plt.title('Aantal noodstoppen per categorie')
plt.xlabel('categorieën')
plt.ylabel('aantal')
plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=p2)

plt.xticks(y_pos, bars)
plt.show()
```

But I don't understand how to change the size of the plot?
because when I use `plt.figure(figsize=(p1,p2))`

I get an empty plot with the correct labels ( But it does apply the size to the piechart i create later? ) 
And the barchart i originally wanted to create has basic 1-8 labels.

I want to change the size based on the amount of bars are created because sometimes the data I use doesn't contain one of the categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With as few changes as humanly possible to your current code, the way to do this is to add the following line right after you define `p1` and `p2`:

```
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(p1,p2)
```

The above will set the size of the current `Figure` object that `pyplot` is using to make plots. In the future, you may way to switch over to using the [`Axes`-based interface to Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes), as it's much more powerful and flexible in general:

```
p = (len(dfrapport.index))

p1 = p * 2.5
p2 = p * 1.5

height = dfrapport['aantal']
bars = dfrapport['soort']
y_pos = np.arange(len(bars))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(p1,p2))
ax = fig.gca()
ax.bar(y_pos, height, color = ['black', 'red','orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan'])

ax.set_title('Aantal noodstoppen per categorie')
ax.set_xlabel('categorieën')
ax.set_ylabel('aantal')
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(which='major', labelsize=p2)

ax.set_xticks(y_pos, bars)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! I used a random guide to generate the chart the first time. 
I started reading this after your first answer: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html  
But you already edited my code haha.

Answer (score 1):

`plt.figure(figsize=(p1,p2))` is the correct approach. The question is hence a bit unclear, because you just need to put it in your code, e.g.

```
p = (len(dfrapport.index))
p1 = p * 2.5
p2 = p * 1.5
plt.figure(figsize=(p1,p2))

# ...

plt.bar(...)
```

This is also shown in the question: [How do you change the size of figures drawn with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib)

Comment: My understanding was that `plt.show()` would display the `plt.figure` and like I said, i get an empty plot with the correct labels. 
If i use `plt.figure` in combination with `plt.bar()` instead of `plt.show()` it would work?

Comment: @MartijnvanAmsterdam You might have been putting the `plt.figure(figsize=(p1,p2))` line after your `plt.bar...` line. That would cause the current figure to get reset, which would explain why you were seeing an empty plot. ImportanceOfBeingErnest is right that if you put the `plt.figure` line above your plotting code, it should work fine.

Comment: Ah I understand now, yes i did place it under my `plt.bar...` but above my `plt.show()`