# How to change size of figures drawn in matplotlib without centering?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm plotting sequential images of a dot going round in a circle. I'm trying to output square images using `plt.savefig()`. The default output has dimensions 640 × 480 (not square).

Using `figure(figsize = (x_size,y_size))`, I can specify the number of inches along each dimension in the output of `plt.savefig()`, as discussed in [How do I change the size of figures drawn with Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib). However this centres the image so that my dot always appears in the centre of the frame.

To be more clear, using the following code I can output square images (500 × 500) of dot going round in circle :

```
for i in range(N):
  x = np.cos(w * t)
  y = np.sin(w * t)
  t += dt
  plt.xlim(-2, 2)
  plt.ylim(-2, 2)
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
  plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o', c='black', s=100)
  plt.axis('off')
  plt.savefig("./fig" + str(i) + ".png")
```

However, the image is shifted along the x, y axis such that the dot always appears in the centre of the image.

How can I output square images without centering the image?

Comment: The size of the figure is independent of the position of the dot. Hence it's not clear what you're asking about. Best show a [mcve] of the problem at hand such that people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Define `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))` before setting `plt.xlim(-2, 2)` and `plt.ylim(-2, 2)`.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54382269/2) to the question [How to change size of figures drawn in matplotlib without centering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54382269/how-to-change-size-of-figures-drawn-in-matplotlib-without-centering) by the OP [J Physics](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9680037/j-physics) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>