# Resizing matplotlib figure after initializing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

How do I resize a matplotlib figure, after I have created/initialized it?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 3))
pd.Series([1, 2, 3]).plot(ax=ax)    
# which command to use to? below obviously does not work
fig.set_figsize((6, 6))
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47018826/4124317) from the duplicate.

Comment: thanks. the second answer is indeed what I needed (i.e. resize after the plot has already been created)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command to use is set_size_inches:

```
fig.set_size_inches((6, 6))
```

To answer my own question (it did not show up in my searches, hopefully this thread will).