# changing the size of subplots with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to plot multiple rgb images with matplotlib

the code I am using is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(0, images):
    test = np.random.rand(1080, 720,3)
    plt.subplot(images,2,i+1)
    plt.imshow(test, interpolation='none')
```

the subplots appear tiny though as thumbnails
How can I make them bigger?
I have seen solutions using

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

syntax before but not with `plt.subplot` ?

Comment: The subplot size is determined by how many subplots you put into the figure; e.g. if you put 10 subplot rows into the figure, each will be (roughly) one tenth of the figure size. You may [create a larger figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib) though.

Answer (score 0):

`plt.subplots` initiates a subplot grid, while `plt.subplot` adds a subplot. So the difference is whether you want to initiate you  plot right away or fill it over time. Since it seems, that you know how many images to plot beforehand, I would also recommend going with subplots.

Also notice, that the way you use `plt.subplot` you generate empy subplots in between the ones you are actually using, which is another reason they are so small.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

images = 4


fig, axes = plt.subplots(images, 1,  # Puts subplots in the axes variable
                         figsize=(4, 10),  # Use figsize to set the size of the whole plot
                         dpi=200,  # Further refine size with dpi setting
                         tight_layout=True)  # Makes enough room between plots for labels

for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    y = np.random.randn(512, 512)
    ax.imshow(y)
    ax.set_title(str(i), fontweight='bold')
```

[image: plot]