# How to set the default figure size and DPI of all plots drawn by `matplotlib.pyplot`

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I know how to set figure size and DPI of one plot by `fig, ax = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8), dpi=140)`.
But I am wondering there is a way that can change the figure size or DPI of all plots without specifying these values each time.
Could anyone help me？
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you change the size of figures drawn with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For your specific case, you probably want to set

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [8.0, 8.0]
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 140
```

This will change the default for this one script.

However, there are a number of ways how you can change the defaults permanently. You could modify the `matplotlibrc` file or create your own style sheet. Please refer to the matplotlib documentation for details:

- https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html
- https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html

Answer (score 4):

**1. Apply to a single file**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = 300
%matplotlib inline
```

**2. Apply to all files**

Find `~\Python37\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\matplotlibrc`. Let `figure.dpi=300`.

This will be overwritten in your next install. Put this file in the following path can avoid being overwritten.

- Unix/Linux:

`$HOME/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc`

`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/matplotlib/matplotlibrc`

- Other platforms:

`$HOME/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`