# Is there a way to stretch my scatter plot vertically and fit a regression curve in it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a data-frame of the following format with 4977 rows x 227 columns, the last column is 'STDEV'

```
 data = {'TCTN':['101', '102', '103', '104'], '0':[626, 866, 1, 474] , '1':[485,182,290,1367], '2':[1985,555,626,8], 'STDEV':[5911,6040,5974,6062]}
```

i created a scatter plot between values of 'TCTN' column and 'STDEV' column i.e, standard deviation of all columns corresponding to specific TCTN numbers :

```
p=plt.scatter(df3['STDEV'].values, df3['TCTN'].values)
```

[image: scatter plot]

i wanted to increase the `figsize` of the plot to make the data-points more distinct using:

```
p=plt.scatter(df3['STDEV'].values, df3['TCTN'].values,figsize=(10,10))
```

but i get  **AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no property 'figsize'**

Also, i want to expand the x-axis between values 5000-70000 so that i can try to fit a regression curve of some sort in it.Please help me out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you change the size of figures drawn with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the size, you can add this line:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
```

Full code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.xlim(5000,7000)
p=plt.scatter(df3['STDEV'].values, df3['TCTN'].values)
```

Although it is not totally clear to me if you meant this with `expand the x-axis between 5000-7000`

Comment: This does increase the figsize of my plot but the datapoints are still not legible , i.e There still exists this huge overlapping column of datapoints in the '6000' mark. Do i try some other plot?

Comment: You can stretch a bit with `plt.xlim(5800,6200)`