# How to make this chart easier to read?

Tags: python

I want to know how to get my x axis labels to display bigger so that the team labels aren't overlapping. I'm sure it's just a matter of configuring the chart size

My code:

```
plt.plot(prem_data.Team, prem_data.attack_scored,'o')
plt.plot(prem_data.Team, prem_data.defence_saves)

plt.xlabel("Team")
plt.ylabel("Attack goals scored & Defence tackles") 
plt.legend(["attack scored", "defence saved"])


plt.show()
```

Comment: `plt.xlabel("Team", labelpad=20)`

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine there being two mutually non-exclusive solutions.

1. Directly alter the size of the font. This can be achieved via calling `plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': <font_size>})`, assuming that you have imported `matplotlib.pyplot` under the alias `plt`, as you have done in the source code provided. You would probably want to set the `<font_size>` to be small to prevent overlapping labels, but this would require some experimentation.
2. Increase the size of the figure. This can be done in a number of ways, but perhaps the simplest method you can implement with minimal edits to your current code would be to use the command `plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = <fig_size>` where `<fig_size>` is a tuple specifying the size of the figure in inches, such as `(10, 5)`.

With some trial and error, you should be able to manipulate the size of the font and the figure to produce a plot with improved readability.

---

Note: The method for altering figure size I introduced above is not the most conventional way to go about this problem. Instead, it is much more common to use `matplotlib.pyplot.figure` or similar variants. For more information, I recommend that you check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib) and the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html).