# What is the equivalent of using attribute "figsize" in Line2D in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

I am trying to take a Line2D plot and change its size to make it bigger in Python. I have tried to change the function to:

```
# Single 1D Discretized Brownian Motion
np.random.seed(5)
fig = plt.figure()

# Initialize the parameters        
T = 1
N = 501 # Number of points, number of subintervals = N-1
dt = T/(N-1) # Time step ()

# time units
t = np.linspace(0,T,N)

# Vectorized option (more efficient)  
dX = np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.randn(1,N)
X = np.cumsum(dX, axis=1)

plt.plot(t, X[0,:],figsize=(15,12))
plt.xlabel('$t$', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel(' $X(t)$', fontsize=15)
plt.title('1D Discretized Brownian Path', fontsize=14)

plt.show()
```

the line of interest is  `plt.plot(t, X[0,:],figsize=(15,12))` that led to the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'figsize'
```

What is an alternative way to change the size of the figure? How does one increase its size in this case? I apologize in advance if this has a obvious answer, I am new to Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`figsize` is a property of [`matplotlib.figure.Figure`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html)s. There are a number of ways to set it (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib)) but the easiest in this case is probably to add

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(15,12))
```

before the call to `plt.plot`, i.e.

```py
# ...
plt.figure(figsize=(15,12))
plt.plot(t, X[0,:])
# ...
```

This will create a `Figure` instance with the specified size and set that instance to be the 'current' figure - which is what `plt.plot` will use.

Comment: Thanks @William-Miller, You sir are a beast. It seems like you answer all the questions here lol. Have a great day!

Comment: @ThamuMnyulwa Only seems that way because you ask good questions, and I'm always happy to help