# How to keep the legend when I save a matplotlib figure as .png

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to save a matplotlib time series plot as png. When I generate the graph I produce also the legend, but I cannot save it in in the .png figure. I cannot save the legend.

```
data_df['point'].plot(linestyle='dashed', label='points')
plt.title('trial')
plt.ylabel('N. of points')
plt.xlabel('Time (days)')
plt.legend(loc='best', frameon=True)
plt.show(block = True)
plt.savefig('figures\\'+'case_1'+'.png', format ='png')
```

The data looks like:

```
Date
2010-01-06    7.54
2010-02-06    9.09
2010-03-06    7.91
2010-04-06    13.27
2010-05-06    7.86
               ...  
2020-03-19    11.95
2020-03-20    8.17
2020-03-21    10.29
2020-03-22    15.86
2020-03-23    7.36
Name: point, Length: 3324, dtype: float64
```

Does anyone know how to keep the legend in my .png figure?

Comment: I think your code should work with no problem... are there any warnings or errors?

Comment: No.. It always finish only with 'Process finished with exit code 0'

Comment: Can you share the data with us?

Comment: I had a similar problem some days ago. The solution was, that the .png was to small and the legend was cut off. Have you tried playing around with figsize? https://stackoverflow.com/a/638443/12934163

Comment: Data added @Anwarvic

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `bbox_inches='tight'` to `.savefig()`, it should keep the legend close enough not to get cut off.