# how to show all 12 month in x axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series

I want to plot something with respect of 12 months. but in figure in x axis, it does not show all 12 month. what I have to do in order to x axis be based on all 12 months?

My code is as follows

```
plt.plot_date(tezos2018['Date'],tezos2018['Market Cap'], linestyle='solid',xdate=True)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
date=dates.DateFormatter( '%b , %d, %Y')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(date)
```

which outputs

[image: The picture of the following code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [`matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator(bymonth=None, bymonthday=1, interval=1, tz=None)`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator) class:

Make ticks on occurrences of each month, e.g., 1, 3, 12.

Mark every month in bymonth; bymonth can be an int or sequence. Default is range(1,13), i.e. every month.

interval is the interval between each iteration. For example, if interval=2, mark every second occurrence.

```py
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

plt.plot_date(tezos2018['Date'],tezos2018['Market Cap'], linestyle='solid',xdate=True)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
date=dates.DateFormatter( '%b , %d, %Y')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(date)

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
```

Comment: Thank you. do you know also how I can make the figure wider?

Comment: @hghg Take a look at [How do you change the size of figures drawn with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib).