# OSMnx: Create rectangular building footprints

Tags: python, osmnx

I'm using the sample "make_plot" function shown in the example page on the OSMnx repo page to generate maps of building footprints.  The output is a square image, is there any way to adjust the height and width to produce a rectangular file?

I made some changes to the example to use the geometries module instead of the deprecated footprints:

```
def make_plot(place, point, dist, network_type='all', bldg_color='#FF0000', dpi=300,
            default_width=1,
            street_widths = {
                "footway": 0.5,
                "steps": 0.5,
                "pedestrian": 0.5,
                "service": 0.5,
                "path": 0.5,
                "track": 0.5,
                "primary": 0.5,
                "secondary": 0.5,
                "trunk": 1,
                "motorway": 2 ,
                }):
gdf = ox.geometries.geometries_from_point(center_point=point, tags={'building':True}, dist=dist)
fig, ax = ox.plot_figure_ground(point=point, dist=dist, network_type=network_type,
                                default_width=default_width, street_widths=street_widths, save=False, show=False, close=True, bgcolor='#343434')
fig, ax = ox.plot.plot_footprints(gdf, ax=ax, color=bldg_color,
                            save=True, show=False, close=True, filepath="images/{}.png".format(place), dpi=dpi)
```

make_plot(place, point, dist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The output is a square image, is there any way to adjust the height and width to produce a rectangular file?

You are querying a square area, so your plot of the results is correspondingly square. If you query a non-square area, you get a non-square plot:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)
gdf = ox.geometries_from_place('Piedmont, CA, USA', tags={'building':True})
fig, ax = ox.plot_footprints(gdf)
```

[image: rectangular plot]

Note that you get a `fig, ax` back, and you can of course resize your figure the [usual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib) matplotlib way: `fig.set_size_inches(9, 3)`. Note that this resizes your figure rather than *stretch* it (e.g., from a square to a rectangle). Also note that all OSMnx plotting functions take an optional `figsize` argument. See [the documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.plot.plot_footprints).

> I made some changes to the example to use the geometries module instead of the deprecated footprints

The [examples](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/v0.16.0/notebooks/10-building-footprints.ipynb) were updated a month ago when OSMnx v0.16.0 was released, to reflect the new `geometries` module. Any references to the deprecated `footprints` module were removed then as well.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.  I didn't adjust figsize because the docstring under the plot_figure_ground function in plot.py said: "figsize : numeric (width, height) of figure, should be equal".  I'll try messing with it though

Comment: That specific helper function exists to create square plots by querying square areas. If you don't want a square study area, don't use that helper function.

Comment: Turns out I was looking at the examples from 0.11 for some reason.  I appreciate your help, osmnx is an incredible package

Comment: I used the updates helper function in the example you linked and the footprints do not fill the image completely, there is a small border around the edge of the map.  How can I generate maps where the footprints and roads fill the entire image?

Comment: Here are two examples, same map, different distances:
[Example 1](https://imgur.com/QGAShPf)
[Example 2](https://imgur.com/FJuVl5a)