# Every time I change the `figsize` the size does not change

Tags: matplotlib, figsize

Here is the code below.

```
plt.figure(figsize=[15,7])
sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(bitcoin_month.Weighted_Price).plot()
print("Dickey–Fuller test: p=%f" % sm.tsa.stattools.adfuller(bitcoin_month.Weighted_Price)[1])
plt.show()
```

When I release it I get the following output.

[image]

Every time I change the `figsize` the size does not change.

Please assist.

Comment: you need to create an Axes object and pass it to `.plot()`

Comment: Can you say something more? Where exactly?

Comment: The plot function of [statsmodels/tsa/seasonal](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/seasonal.html#DecomposeResult) creates its own new figure and axes. You can change them with `fig = plt.gcf()` and `fig.set_size_inches(15, 7)` after the call to `... .plot()`. See [How do you change the size of figures drawn with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib). Another option is `plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (15,7)` before calling `...plot()`.