# save the plot in python with 1920 pixels by 1080

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to save my plot in python with size 1920* 1080 pixel. The way that I am doing now is

```
plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 12))
```

Could you please help me with that? Thank you so much.

I tried to change the dpi and etc. However, it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fig.set_size_inches(19.20, 10.80)` to make your plots 1920*1080 pixels at **100 dpi**.

There are a lot of resources that shows how to change fig size;

A stackoverflow thread- [How do I change the size of figures drawn with Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-i-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib)

[A FreeCodeCamp page](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/matplotlib-figure-size-change-plot-size-in-python/)

Comment: Thank you. I will check this. However, the first step gives me the error, 'tuple' object has no attribute 'set_size_inches'. I use 'plt.subplots' for my figure.

Comment: @Jessicatrevor `'tuple' object has no attribute 'set_size_inches'`  means what you think is `fig` is in reality a tuple.  You probably did `fig = plt.subplots(...)` instead of `fig, ax = plt.subplots(...)`.